# An analogue of the Milnor-Švarc lemma for Busemann boundaries

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, alexandrov-geometry

The Milnor-Švarc lemma, is, without doubt, regarded as one of the most important statements in geometric group theory. (Edit) One of the corollaries of this lemma says that if a hyperbolic group $G$ acts geometrically on a hyperbolic space $X$, then the Gromov boundaries of $G$ and $X$ turn out to be homeomorphic.

Now, suppose that $(X, d_X)$ is a complete CAT(0)-space, and $G$ is a finitely-generated group equipped with a geometric action on $X$. Let us fix a point $x_0 \in X$ with the trivial stabilizer, and consider a distance on $G$, which is defined as follows: $d(g_1, g_2) = d_X(g_1.x_0, g_2.x_0)$. We need the stabilizer to be trivial so that $d$ becomes a well-defined distance.

> **Conjecture:** Fix a point $x_0 \in X$. The restriction map $r : \partial_B(X, d_X) \rightarrow \partial_B(G, d)$, where
> $$
> r(h)(g) = h(g.x_0) \text{ for any  } h \in \partial_B(X, d_X).
> $$
> is a homeomorphism of Busemann boundaries $\partial_B(X, d_X)$ and $\partial_B(G, d)$. Moreover, if we define the Busemann function and the Busemann cocycle as follows:
> $$
> b_X : X \times \partial X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad b_X(x, \xi) = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}(d(x, \xi(t)) - t),
> $$
> $$
> c_B : G \times \partial_B(G, d), \quad c_B(g, \xi) := \xi(g^{-1}) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \xi} (d(x, g^{-1}) - d(e, x)),
> $$
> then
> $$
> c_B(g, r(\xi)) = b_X(g^{-1}.x_0, \xi).
> $$

Keep in mind that $r$ is well-defined because for complete CAT(0)-spaces the Gromov and Busemann boundaries are homeomorhpic.

**This statement, if true, looks quite natural and should be well-known, but I failed to find this result in standard geometric group theory textbooks.**

---

Because I haven't found a proof of this fact, I will attempt to prove this fact myself.

For any $y \in X$ define a function $h_y(x) = d_X(x,y) - d_X(y,x_0)$.

Showing that $r$ is surjective is not that difficult, because $\partial_B(X, d_X)$ is sequentially compact. If a sequence $(h_{g_i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $h_{g_i}(x) := d(x, g_i.x_0) - d(g_i.x_0, x_0)$, converges to $h$ in $\partial_B(G, d)$, then we can find a subseqeuence $(h_{g_{i_k}.x_0})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges in $\partial_B(X, d_X)$, but this limit, restricted to the orbit $Gx_0$, has to be equal to $h$.

To show that $r$ is injective (this is the non-trivial part!), we need to prove the following statement: if $\xi_1, \xi_2$ are non-asymptotical geodesical rays  in $\partial(X)$, then $$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}(b(\xi_2(s), \xi_1) + s) = \infty.$$ Because these rays are non-asymptotic, we use the fact that the CAT(0)-angle between them is non-trivial, which allows us to use the CAT(0)-law of cosines in a nice way, so that we get

$$
\begin{gathered}
        \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{t^2 + s^2 - 2st \cos( \angle_{x_0}(\xi_1, \xi_2) - \varepsilon)} - t \le \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} d(\xi_1(t), \xi_2(s)) - t \le \\
        \le \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{t^2 + s^2 - 2st \cos( \angle_{x_0}(\xi_1, \xi_2) + \varepsilon)} - t,
    \end{gathered}  
$$

for some very small $\varepsilon > 0$ and a big enough $s > 0$. Here I refer to the Propositon II.9.8(1) in Bridson-Haefliger. Keep in mind that these limits can be computed explicitly, and we finish the argument by taking $\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow \infty}$ and applying the squeeze theorem:
$$
-s ( \cos( \angle(\xi_1, \xi_2) - \varepsilon) - 1) \le b(\xi_2(s), \xi_1) + s \le -s (\cos( \angle(\xi_1, \xi_2) + \varepsilon) - 1).
$$

Suppose that $r$ isn't injective, then there are distinct horofunctions $h_1, h_2$ which coincide on $Gx_0$. However, because the fundamental domain is compact, and horofunctions are 1-Lipschitz, we get $|h_1 - h_2|$ is a uniformly bounded function on $X$. However, $X$ is CAT(0), so we can consider the corresponding rays $\xi_1, \xi_2$. Due to our assumptions, they are non-asymptotic, and we get
$$
\sup_{t} |h_2(\xi_1(t)) - h_1(\xi_1(t))| = \sup_{t} |h_2(\xi_1(t)) + t| = \infty,
$$
and this yields a contradiction with the uniform boundedness of $|h_1 - h_2|$.

---

If this "theorem" is true, then we can use it to explicitly recover the Busemann cocycle for any hyperbolic group acting on a hyperbolic space for which we have a nice description of the Busemann function ($\mathbb{H}^n$, for example). Also, we could use this statement as a *tremendously inefficient* way to check whether a particular non-elementary hyperbolic group $G$ is not CAT(0): consider **all** left-invariant distances $d$ on $G$, and prove that for any such $d$ the Busemann boundary $\partial_B(G, d)$ is not homeomorphic to its Gromov boundary $\partial G$. Of course, such an example isn't known...

**So, here are my questions: is this a known generalization, and are there better applications? I do admit that due to the fact that the Busemann boundary is not a quasi-isometric invariant of a metric space, we don't have as much freedom and flexibility as in the hyperbolic setting. However, maybe we can use a statement like this in a different way?**

---

Edit: Indeed, as indicated in Moishe Kohan's comment, this looks like a standard application of some properties of CAT(0)-angles between geodesic rays. As far as I understand, the argument presented in my answer can be recovered from the proof of Theorem II.4.4 in the W.Ballman's textbook "Lectures on spaces of nonpositive curvature". However, I am still interested in possible applications, if there are any.

Comment: 1. MS Lemma is **very different** from the statement that you wrote. 2. It is better to work with the horofunction compactification than with geodesic rays (the result is the same for CAT(0) spaces). Then your claim becomes: if $X$ is proper CAT(0) space and $Y\subset X$ is an $R$-net, then the induced map of horoboundaries $\partial_h Y\to \partial_h X$  is a homeomorphism. This claim is just an exercise. See Chapter II in Ballmann's book.

Comment: I agree that my formulation of MS is massively oversimplified, I just thought it would make the comparison more evident, maybe I should edit my question accordingly. And thank you for the reference, I should take a look at it. As I thought. this claim is, indeed, a known statement!

Comment: Not that it is written down somewhere but, given the alternative definition of the Busemann boundary for CAT(0) spaces, it is merely an exercise.

Comment: The Milnor-Schwarz lemma was proved in the 1950's while Gromov-hyperbolic spaces/groups were introduced in the late 1980's... The statement is not about boundaries. It's rather a comparison of metrics between a group and space on which it acts. It can of course be combined with Gromov's result that a QI between Gromov-hyperbolic spaces passes to a homeomorphism of the boundaries; the main pre-Gromov contribution to such a result is maybe part of the proof of Mostow's rigidity theorem.

Comment: @YCor: indeed, it was proved by Schwarz in 1955 and not by Milnor until 1968. Given the big time lag, it's slightly amazing that we still associate Milnor's name with it.